# Influencers and Influencees in Klout

Tags: klout

If Klout says that I am influencing 10 people on Twitter, I see that they are arranged in decreasing order of a numerical score. Is this score attached to each of the person the Klout score of that person, or is it the extent to which I am influencing them?

If it is the former, how can I determine the latter score?

Comment: What's your *coding* question here?

Comment: Yes. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. You've tagged your question "java" - why? Are you trying to do something in Java? If so, please describe what you've tried, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Klout score of that person.